# Reset network settings

Tags: netsh

In Windows, I ran the command `netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Wi-Fi" static 192.168.3.8 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.1`. I didn't really know what I was doing and now my Internet is not working. What should I do?

Comment: Try TCP/IP Reset:   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the command `netsh interface address name="Wi-Fi" DHCP`. I don't know why but it worked.

Comment: It worked because it told your computer to stop using the hard-coded values you gave it in the earlier command with the "static" parameter, and to instead ask other devices on your network (likely, it was your router that answered) for guidance on what to use for network settings. (The process of asking for and receiving that guidance is called DHCP.)

Comment: this does not work. https://superuser.com/questions/1787113/how-to-reset-ip-and-dns-to-automatic-dhcp-by-cmd-in-win-10-11-to-all-network-i